# How to find the optimal number of clusters?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I know this question has already been asked, but I am failing to implement a decent plot for the following code:

```
options(digits=1)
set.seed(2014)

mydata <- matrix(seq(1,360),nrow=10,ncol=36)
wss <- c()
for (i in 1:19) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(x=mydata,centers=seq(1,360,length.out=20)[i])$withinss)
plot(1:9, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
```

It produces the following error

```
Error in sample.int(m, k) : 
cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

Comment: Try it with `mydata <- matrix(runif(720), ncol=2)`.

Comment: It looks like you have  typo: replace `for (i in 1:19)` with `for (i in 1:9)`. Aso, centers is the *number of cluster centers* (hence the number of clusters), so replace `centers=seq(...)` with `centers=i`.

Comment: @jlhoward my intention was to do a random allocation of `centers` by using the line `seq(1,360,length.out=20)[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little spark in the dark!

```
options(digits=1)
set.seed(2014)

mydata <- seq(from=1,to=365)
wss <- c()
for (i in 5:15){
wss[i-4] <- sum(kmeans(mydata,centers=floor(seq(from=1,to=365,length.out=i)[-i]))$withinss)
}
plot(1:15,wss,type="b",xlab="Number of Clusters",ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
```

Does that make sense? @jlhoward @jbaums

Answer (score 3):

`kmeans` assumes that each row is your data is an observation. So if you have `k` rows in `x`,  the results of `$clusters` will be of lenth `k`.  Here your test data has 10 rows. Yet you are specifying `centers=20` when `i=2` There is no way that 10 observations can have 20 different clusters.